# Find $\phi(x+ct)+\phi(x-ct)$ defined in terms of absolute values in terms of a four condition piecewise function

Tags: absolute-value

Assume $b,a \in \mathbb{R}$

$$\phi(x)=\begin{cases} 
      b-\dfrac{b|x|}{a} & |x| <a \\
      0 & |x|>a
   \end{cases}$$

$$b-\dfrac{b|x|}{a}= \begin{cases}
b-\dfrac{bx}{a} & x \geq 0\\
b+\dfrac{bx}{a} & x<0\end{cases}$$

How to find $$\phi(x+ct)+\phi(x-ct)$$ in terms of a four-condition piecewise function?

I did some algebra to obtain that

$$\phi(x+ct)=\begin{cases}
b-\dfrac{b|x+ct|}{a} & x \in (-a-ct,a-ct)\\
0 & x \notin (-a-ct,a-ct)\end{cases}$$

$$\phi(x-ct)=\begin{cases} b-\dfrac{b|x-ct|}{a} & x \in (ct-a,a+ct) \\ 0 & x \notin (ct-a,a+ct)\end{cases}$$

I find adding this piecewise functions together hard as a result of the constructive and destructive interference where there is overlap in their supports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be precisely what you want, but if you just want a closed form without worrying about piecewise components, then using the fact that the [Heavyside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) can be expressed in terms of the absolute value:

$$H(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{|x|}{x}\right)$$

We find that your function, $\phi$, can be expressed as

$$\phi(x)=\left(b-\frac{b|x|}{a}\right)H(x+a)H(a-x),$$

which then can be substituted into $\phi(x+ct)+\phi(x-ct)$. Although this is equivalent to your piecewise expression, given your bounds, it is undefined when $x=\pm a$. If you want it to be continuous, you can use the alternative definition
$$H(x)=\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{1+2^{-x}}\right\rfloor.$$

Comment: Does this make graphing my function of the sum of phis, any easier?

Comment: @Germania, certainly! You can play with [the graph here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/brky6rzyao) on Desmos!